# Need Help with nRF905 Transceiver Module on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero, spi, arduino, radio

I recently bought a nRF905 Transceiver Module from Jaycar and am wondering how to use it. It is meant for an Arduino and I have found some libraries for it ([nRF905 Library For Arduino - GitHub](https://github.com/ZakKemble/nRF905-arduino/tree/master))

I need some help finding/creating a way to connect to a Raspberry Pi Zero or 3B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget the Arduino code - adapting this would be more work that writing new code. This device uses SPI - if you can't find existing code it would be simple enough to write code using any SPI library and the data sheet.

Comment: Thanks @Milliways, I was found some python code ([nRF905 Python3 Library](https://forum.core-electronics.com.au/t/nrf905-python-3-library-raspberry-pi/13808)) and tested it on both my Pi Zero 2 W and my Pi 3B. Since I only have one module I was wondering if I could use one pi to receive data with the module and and another to transmit. I am aware that pis can transmit FM radio at many frequencies without any external connections (apart from an antenna maybe), do you think it would be possible to transmit that data from the pi? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: I discourage anyone from using pifm which is an unlicensed broadcast and outputs  spurious out of band emissions and is illegal in many countries.

Comment: So @Milliways, should I just buy another module then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Transceiver is a combined receiver and transmitter and to have communication between devices wireless you need two Transceivers to send data between two points.

And the nRF905 Transceiver module isn't made specifically for Arduino, its a module with a radio interface, 433/868/915MHz ISM (Industrial, Scientific, and Medical) band in one end and in the other end it has a SPI interface.

Raspberry Pi has SPI interface (one or several, depending on model) and Arduino's has also SPI interface. SPI is quite common.